# Stuck at purple screen when booting (GTX 1080) 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver

I am getting stuck at a purple screen when trying to boot Ubuntu using the GTX 1080ti. 
There are literally dozens of questions describing the same problem but none of the answers are solving my problem.

The most common answer is to boot using the integrated graphics card, install the Nvidia drivers, and then reboot the system with SecureBoot off (and through the 1080 this time).

I tried that but still get the hanging purple screen. I've tried with both nvidia-375 (apt-get) and nvidia-384 (ppa), but neither seem to work. It's still just stuck at the purple screen.

Any ideas?

Video card: *Nvidia GTX 1080ti*

Motherboard: *ASRock z270 K6*

Ubuntu: *16.04.3*

Comment: What happens when you press ctrl+alt+f1? Can you see the terminal?

Comment: No terminal. Only thing I'm able to do is press escape during boot to get to the grub menu and cli